# Change user permissions on files/directories where user = fred recursively

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

I was wondering if there is a way to change the owner permissions of a file only is the owner is currently "fred" for example, leave all groups the same.

The reason for this is that I have recently been forced to login to SFTP via a different user and need to update all of the previous owned files to the new user. Although I dont want to change every files permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have permission to change ownership, try this:

```
find /path/to/your/folder -user fred -exec chown <new_user> '{}' \;
```